# How to modify builtin open path in python test?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest, fixtures

I have a function which writes to a specific file. I want to mock the file name, so that I can test how the function works with a different location. Below is the code that I wrote:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def change_output_file(mocker):
    orig =builtins.open

    def fake(file_name):
        return orig('xml_test_file.xml','wb')

    mocker.patch('builtins.open', new=fake)


class SomeClass():
    def run(self):
        output_file ="xml_initial_file.xml"
        print("Output file= ",output_file)
        f = open(output_file,'wb')
        # print("Output file= ",f)

def test_change_name(change_output_file):
    class_instance = SomeClass()
    print(class_instance.run()) #to change xml_initial_file.xml with xml_test_file.xml
```

But this test gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: change_name() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I think this is because of the 'wb' argument, but how can I change the mock method to work for writing to a different location than the initial one?

Comment: You are not showing what `change_name` actually is.

Comment: Actually, now I see that you probably meant to use `fake` instead of `change_name`. In this case you forgot to add the second argument to `fake` - as you call `open` with 2 arguments, you need to also have 2 arguments in your fake implementation.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen i modified it, to use the ```fake``` function. But how can I pass the two arguments to it?

Comment: You are already passing the arguments, you need to define them, e.g. `def fake(file_name, mode):`.